# Callback for registered hotkey using user32.dll library (c#)

Tags: c#

I tried this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FL_y8GT1L7E
But after I register the hotkey, it is registered, but the callback just doesn't work.
When calling WndProc, the keyPressed.Msg doesn't equal to 0x0312 which means key press.
Any suggestions for creating a callback for a registered hotkey?

this is the class which registers and unregisters the hotkeys:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Hotkey
    {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    private IntPtr _hWnd;

    public Hotkey(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        this._hWnd = hWnd;
    }

    public enum fsmodifiers
    {
        Alt = 0x0001,
        Control = 0x0002,
        Shift = 0x0004,
        Window = 0x0008
    }

    public void RegisterHotkeys()
    {
        RegisterHotKey(IntPtr.Zero, 1, (uint)fsmodifiers.Control, (uint)Keys.B);
    }

    public void UnregisterHotkeys()
    {
        UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr.Zero, 1);
    }
}
}
```

and the current callback is this:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message keyPressed)
    {
        if(keyPressed.Msg == 0x0312)
            Console.WriteLine();

        base.WndProc(ref keyPressed);
    }
```

0x0312 is the value of key press in windows.
but I set a breakpoint where `Console.WriteLine()` but it never gets there.

This is a windows forms application.

Comment: First of all I suggest to rewrite your post following [StackOverflow rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): `Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.`

Comment: @SimoneCifani edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the native function RegisterHotKey(...) you miss the window handle (hWnd).

Try this:

```
class Hotkey
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    private IntPtr _hWnd;

    public Hotkey(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        this._hWnd = hWnd;
    }

    public enum fsmodifiers
    {
        Alt = 0x0001,
        Control = 0x0002,
        Shift = 0x0004,
        Window = 0x0008
    }

    public void RegisterHotkeys()
    {
        RegisterHotKey(this._hWnd, 1, (uint)fsmodifiers.Control, (uint)Keys.B);
    }

    public void UnregisterHotkeys()
    {
        UnregisterHotKey(this._hWnd, 1);
    }
}
```

To get the handle of a windows form use:

```
this.Handle
```

Comment: thank you it worked!
The problem was that I used `FindWindow()` function which used a specific string to identify my form's window, and probably I typed it wrong.
`this.Handle` is much better for getting the current window.